# How to make unity not pick the same number twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The program is a simple number guessing game however when i randomize the guesses unity tends to pick the same number multiple times is there a way to have it know what numbers it already picked? an also is there a way to make it automatically go to the lose scene if it can't pick another number? any help is appreciated ^_^

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NumberGuesser : MonoBehaviour {

int min;
int max;
int guess;
int maxGuessesAllowed = 15;
public Text text;
//guess = (max + min) / 2;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    min = 1;
    max = 1000;
    NextGuess();
    max = max + 1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void guessHigher () {
    min = guess;
    NextGuess ();
}
public void guessLower() {
        max = guess;
        NextGuess();
    }
void NextGuess(){
    guess = (max + min) / 2;
    //guess = Random.Range (min,max);//Randomizes Guesses
    //print (guess);
    text.text = guess.ToString ();
    maxGuessesAllowed = maxGuessesAllowed - 1;
    if (maxGuessesAllowed <= 0) {
        Application.LoadLevel ("Win");
    }
}
}//main
```

Comment: Well, you can make the function NextGuess to return the guessed value and store it on a list (from where you call it). That way you can keep track of the values used.
But as it is, it is difficult to understand the problem as not all the relevant code has been shown. Where do you call this method from?

Comment: Create a list of all the possible guesses and then choose a number randomly from that list and remove it. Keep going until all numbers are removed or the game has been won. This prevents guessing the same number twice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<int> alreadyGuessed = new List<int>();
...

int NextGuess()
{
    int theGuess = Random.Range(min, max);
    while(alreadyGuessed.Contains(theGuess))
        theGuess = Random.Range(min, max);

    alreadyGuessed.Add(theGuess);
    return theGuess;
}
```

It keeps track of what has been guessed and keeps on guessing until the guess has not been guessed before.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this at top of your code

```
List<int> used = new List<int>();
```

you may want to add this using too

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

and then change your `NextGuess` function to this

```
void NextGuess()
{
    guess = Random.Range (min,max);
    while(used.Contains(guess))
        guess = Random.Range (min,max);
    used.Add (guess);
    text.text = guess.ToString ();
    maxGuessesAllowed = maxGuessesAllowed - 1;
    if (maxGuessesAllowed <= 0) {
        Application.LoadLevel ("Win");
    }
}
```